# High voltage to TTL conversion

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, high-voltage, ttl

I'm designing a circuit that is going to sense the existence of high voltage DC(400V+) via microcontroller. I've already designed it for AC voltage using an optocoupler; however, I will  not able to use an isolation component for DC detection. I'm planning to use a resistor and high voltage diode pair at the input level, and open collector npn transistor for the microcontroller end; but, I don't have an idea how to convert that high voltage to TTL level.

I appreciate any help or guidance to this problem.

edit: As requested, I add schematics of my AC detection circuit.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you use an optocoupler for DC?

Comment: just a restriction. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: *shrug* I'd still isolate it, even if I had to use a LED, a phototransistor, and a piece of heatshrink tubing.

Comment: Can you post a schematic of both your AC and DC circuits and show how you want to interface them to the MCU, please?

Comment: I added the AC detection schematic. DC is what I'm asking :) @EMFields

Comment: What's your AC input voltage and frequency?

Comment: 220Vrms/50Hz @EMFields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the LTspice schematic, with the code following it if you want to play with the circuit. R1, R2, and R3 are used instead of a single resistor because of the maximum voltage allowed across a single resistor, something like 150V peak.

Check the voltage spec's of the resistors you want to use and make sure it won't be exceeded regardless of the input voltage or the tolerances of the resistors.

[image]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 2680 692
WIRE -672 -2176 -1440 -2176
WIRE -576 -2176 -672 -2176
WIRE -672 -2144 -672 -2176
WIRE -672 -2032 -672 -2064
WIRE -576 -2032 -672 -2032
WIRE -672 -1984 -672 -2032
WIRE -1280 -1936 -1344 -1936
WIRE -1152 -1936 -1200 -1936
WIRE -1024 -1936 -1072 -1936
WIRE -880 -1936 -944 -1936
WIRE -800 -1936 -880 -1936
WIRE -736 -1936 -800 -1936
WIRE -1440 -1872 -1440 -2176
WIRE -1344 -1872 -1344 -1936
WIRE -880 -1872 -880 -1936
WIRE -800 -1872 -800 -1936
WIRE -1440 -1744 -1440 -1792
WIRE -1344 -1744 -1344 -1792
WIRE -1344 -1744 -1440 -1744
WIRE -880 -1744 -880 -1808
WIRE -880 -1744 -1344 -1744
WIRE -800 -1744 -800 -1792
WIRE -800 -1744 -880 -1744
WIRE -672 -1744 -672 -1888
WIRE -672 -1744 -800 -1744
WIRE -576 -1744 -672 -1744
WIRE -1440 -1680 -1440 -1744
FLAG -1440 -1680 0
FLAG -576 -2176 MCU_Vcc
FLAG -576 -2032 MCU_I/O
FLAG -576 -1744 MCU_GND
SYMBOL res -1184 -1952 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL npn -736 -1984 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL res -688 -2160 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -816 -1888 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage -1344 -1888 R0
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 400 1 1ms 1ms 100ms)
SYMBOL diode -864 -1808 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL voltage -1440 -1888 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res -1056 -1952 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
SYMBOL res -928 -1952 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1Meg
TEXT -1426 -1712 Left 2 !.tran 2 startup uic
```

Comment: I'm not that much experienced with LTSpice (generally using spice of CAD drawing). Could you tell me how to operate this code piece? I'm getting an error "Multiple Instance of Flag".

Comment: @vilacikovski: Sure.  First, go [here](http://www.linear.com/designtools/software/) and download LTspice IV. Then copy the code I posted as a file with any name you want and a suffix of.asc into a folder of your choice. Left click on the file amd LTspice should start up, find the file, and display the schematic.  To run the simulation, right click anywhere on the background of the schematic and then left click on "Run"

Comment: One final question I'd like to ask. Using 1Meg resistor keep 134V. Considering the peak voltage for 805 package resistor is 150V, isn't the safe margin is a bit low? 4 resistors seem safer. What do you think?

Comment: @vilacikovski: I think you're right!  You should also check how much power the resistors will dissipate and make sure they're rated properly.

Comment: As long as at least two resistors are connected, power dissipation wouldn't be a problem. 22mW/125mW for 4 resistors, safe enough. Total 0.1~0.2W of power will be consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Enable the internal pullup resistor on the MCU input and use the transistor to pull it to ground. That way you don't need to worry about what voltage the MCU uses.

Comment: So, is it enough to drive a power transistor with open collector configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't need a power transistor for this. The collector current itself only needs to be about 50mA, but even saturating it won't dissipate much power.

Comment: Applying 400V directly to transistor still makes no sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: 50mA seems like a lot for an MCU's internal pullup, yes?

Comment: @vilacikovski: Earlier you said that the 400VDC was to be applied to an open-collector NPN through a resistance and - presumably - an anti-parallel diode pair from the base to GND.  Has that changed?

Comment: @EMFields: The output impedance of the transistor needs to be low enough to pull the input below Vil.

Comment: No. The schematic I added belongs to my AC design. With optocoupler, 470k and the npn, I can generate active low signal to uP. For DC voltage, I will not use an optocoupler or any other isolated components. What I am asking is how to interface that high voltage to uP. Open collector configuration is just an idea. @EMFields

Comment: The transistor is fine, but you can't connect the 400V directly to the base since you'll blow up the transistor.

Comment: @vilacikovski: OK then, as I understand it you already have a circuit to detect AC which you'll connect to the MCU through one I/O, and you _want_ a circuit which will detect DC which you'll connect to the MCU through another I/O. Right?

Comment: Exactly @EMFields. 
Yes, I know. Actually, what I am asking is how to drive that transistor.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: OK, and since Vce(sat) will be about 0.3V, that's certainly lower than Vil at any reasonable collector current. The real question, then, is why do you think that an MCU's internal pullup is going to look like 100 ohms?

Comment: @vilacikovski: I've posted an answer for you.

Comment: I saw it, thank you. Is your selections for D1 arbitrary? If it is not, why do I need fast switching diode? @EMFields

Comment: @vilacikovski: It's semi-arbitrary since its switching speed doesn't matter, and you could probably eliminate it altogether with no ill effect.  I just put it in there in case something goes awry and tries to pull Q1's base way negative.  Plus, it's ubiquitous and cheap.